# my Spring CustomSecurityExpressionRoot not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a New Security Expression in my spring project but it not working. Here is my code.

Firstly, i make a `CustomPermissionEvaluator` which implement `PermissionEvaluator`:

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        if ((auth == null) || (targetDomainObject == null) || !(permission instanceof String)) {
            return false;
        }
        final String targetType = targetDomainObject.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
        return hasPrivilege(auth, targetType, permission.toString().toUpperCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        if ((auth == null) || (targetType == null) || !(permission instanceof String)) {
            return false;
        }
        return hasPrivilege(auth, targetType.toUpperCase(), permission.toString().toUpperCase());
    }

    private boolean hasPrivilege(Authentication auth, String targetType, String permission) {
        for (final GrantedAuthority grantedAuth : auth.getAuthorities()) {
            if (grantedAuth.getAuthority().startsWith(targetType) && grantedAuth.getAuthority().contains(permission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And `CustomSecurityExpressionRoot` implement `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations`

```
public class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSecurityExpressionRoot.class);

    protected final Authentication authentication;
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver;
    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();
    private String defaultRolePrefix = "ROLE_";
    private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;

    public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Authentication object cannot be null");
        }
        this.authentication = authentication;
        log.debug("Custom Security Expression Root ran");
    }

    // @Override
    // Override some method


    // test
    public boolean isAdmin(Long groupId){
        log.debug("Group Id is {}", groupId);
        return true;
    }

    public static <T> boolean allIsNull(T... items) {
        for (T item : items) if (item != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

And then, I create `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` which will `Override method createSecurityExpressionRoot`

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    private final AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setMyRepository(applicationContext.getBean(MyRepository.class));
        return root;
    }
}
```

And finally, I configure the application

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

And I added `isAdmin()` restriction to 1 of my API

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "MyResource";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final MyService myService;

    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    private final MyKafkaService KafkaService;

    public MyResource(GroupMemberService myService, MyRepository myRepository, MyKafkaService myKafkaService) {
        this.myService = myService;
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
        this.KafkaService = KafkaService;
    }
    
    @PreAuthorize("isAdmin(#week)")
    @GetMapping("/todo/{week}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<TodoDTO>> getAllTodoInWeek(@PathVariable Long week, Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Todo");
        Page<TodoDTO> page = myService.findAllByWeek(week, pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
}
```

I was excited to use postman to test this api and eagerly waiting for the desired result. But i get error `Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method isAdmin() cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'isAdmin()'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:33)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at vn.vnedu.studyspace.group_store.web.rest.GroupMemberResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df9b89b9.getAllGroupMembersInGroup(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:280)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:260)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1449)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method isAdmin() cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:135)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:308)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method isAdmin() cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
```

Please tell me where I went wrong.
Thank so much

Comment: Apart from the fact you made this overly complex? You don't need a custom expression root or permission handler. Just create a bean with the `isAdmin` method and reference that in your expression `@yourbean.isAdmin`. Also your `isAdmin` takes a parameter, your expression you write doesn't provide that parameter `groupId` and as there is no `isAdmin()` method you get this error.

Comment: @M.Deinum I corrected the example `@PreAuthorize("isAdmin(#groupId)")` and i get error `ethod isAdmin(java.lang.Long) cannot be found on...`. I need to do that because I want to learn how to make custom security expression. I followed the [tutorial of baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression)

Comment: No you don't need to do this. You can just create that method in a bean and do the exact same and use it as I stated. Which is far easier than creating a custom expression thing, which isn't even recommended anymore by the Spring Security Team.

Comment: I will follow your instructions. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally don't use a custom `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` instead just write a class which does what you want. Register that as a bean (make it an `@Component`) and reference that in your expression.

Something like the following

```java
@Component
public class OurSecurity {

  public boolean isAdmin(Long groupId) {
    log.debug("Group Id is {}", groupId);
    return true;
  }
}
```

If you setup Spring Boot correctly this will be picked up and registered as a bean. In SpEL you can reference a bean using the `@`. So rewrite your expression to the following.

```java
@PreAuthorize("@ourSecurity.isAdmin(#week)")
```

Which will now call the method on the provided bean. You can now remove all the custom parts and just use this. This is easier than trying to replace the moving parts in Spring Security.

You can also use the same expression with the `access` method on the `HttpSecurity.antMatcher` (and other matches) to compose/write security expressions.

Comment: It works great. Thank you very much. This is much easier than custom`MethodSecurityExpressionOperations`. Xin chân thành cảm ơn

Comment: this should learn you to stop following Baldungs tutorials blindly as they many times contain just faulty information.

Comment: Best answer ever!

Answer (score 0):

For the once which are also facing this error:

```
"Failed to evaluate expression '@customSecurityExpression.hasGVO('ABCDE')'",
```

We have created a utility library/dependency for all our spring boot resource (3.1.5) servers, so we only need to maintain the functionality once.

Custom @PreAuthorize check - code snipped:

```
@PreAuthorize("@customSecurityExpression.hasGVO('ABCDE')")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Schema(description = "Admin permission 'ABCDE' required.")
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface AuthorizeHasAdminRights {
}
```

While debugging DefaultListableBeanFactory.java, we encountered that our spring bean (@Component) was defined with a full qualified package path, so therefore the bean could not be found in @PreAuthorize of the resource server.

**Solution:**
We had to defined a dedicated component name via

```
@Component("customSecurityExpression")
public class CustomSecurityExpression { ... }
```

so DefaultListableBeanFactory#getBeanDefinition(String beanName) was able to find the spring bean in the field: beanDefinitionMap.

*Disclaimer: This may only occur if your spring bean gets created in an dependency*