# GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration is deprecated in spring boot 3, how to create Custom Expresion handler in 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently, I have created custom expression handler by overriding the `createExpressionHandler` function from `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. The code is

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
    
}
```

-- CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler class

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
            MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setG(this.applicationContext.getBean(CustomTraversalSource.class));
        return root;
    }
    
    //This setter method will be called from the config class
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
    }
}
```

And CustomPermissionEvaluator

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        if ((authentication == null) || (targetDomainObject == null) || !(permission instanceof String)){
            return false;
        }
        String targetType = targetDomainObject.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
        
        return hasPrivilege(authentication, targetType, permission.toString().toUpperCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType,
            Object permission) {
        if ((authentication == null) || (targetType == null) || !(permission instanceof String)) {
            return false;
        }
        return hasPrivilege(authentication, targetType.toUpperCase(), 
          permission.toString().toUpperCase());
    }

    private boolean hasPrivilege(Authentication authentication, String targetType, String permission) {
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            if (grantedAuth.getAuthority().startsWith(targetType) && 
              grantedAuth.getAuthority().contains(permission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need all this code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70364411/my-spring-customsecurityexpressionroot-not-working/70365925#70365925

Answer (score 10):

## Expression Handler

In order to customize expression handling mechanism [Reference documentation of Spring Security 6.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#_customizing_authorization) suggests registering `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` as a Bean in the Context, by defining `@Bean` annotated method in the configuration class. The method is advised to be marked with `static` modifier, so that it gets executed, and a custom expression handler gets registered in the Context before the configuration class would be instantiated and initialized.

> If you need to customize the way that expressions are handled,
> you can expose a custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, like so:
>
> ```
> @Bean
> static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler
> methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
>     // instantiating the handler
>     return handler;
> }
> ```
>
> We expose MethodSecurityExpressionHandler using a `static` method to
> ensure that Spring publishes it before it initializes Spring
> Security’s method security `@Configuration` classes.

## [`@EnableMethodSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.0/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableMethodSecurity.html)

[`@EnableMethodSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.0/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableMethodSecurity.html) annotation is a recommended replacement for deprecated <del>`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`</del>.

Its property `prePostEnabled` is by default set to `true`.

So to enable usage of `@PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize` and `@PreFilter/@PostFilter` which are the most widely used annotations for customizing access control on the method-level, you can apply `@EnableMethodSecurity` without providing any arguments.

Comment: however , the question was different : ..... class GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration is deprecated...  how to create Custom Expresion handler ....?  for example, how to redo what is described in the article :   ttps://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access  . That is, to remove the outdated API

Comment: @skyho Oops, I must have been very sleepy, while writing this. Thanks for pointing that, fixed the answer, and approved yours.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DenyMethodSecurityConfig {
    
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

If you need an annotation @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity that to replace on @EnableMethodSecurity (note: prePostEnabled() default true).

If you use an annotated approach, then set this annotation above the class where you use annotations: @Pre/Post***,
since incorrect work is possible if you set annotation @EnableMethodSecurity above the class that only describes the configurations (marked as @Configuration),
you may observe incorrect operation of the authorization mechanism. However, I suggest you check it yourself.